# How can i switch the main view controller ios5?

Tags: ios, uiview, uiviewcontroller

I want to implement authorization for my application. If the authorization function returns yes, i want to switch my main view controller and assign my second view controller as initial view controller. I don't want to see authorization view any more after the function returns yes. 
What should i try?

Like transitionFromViewController or not?

Answer (score 0):

Just load the main view controller and if you need to authenticate present a modal view over the view controller

```
[self presentModalViewController:myLoginViewController animated:NO];
```

or

```
[self presentViewController:myLogingViewController animated:NO completion:NULL];
```

Comment: this code schould be in you main view controller e.g in `viewWillAppear` . Is your new view controller initialized ?

Comment: My code like this : - (IBAction)loginCheck:(id)sender {
    if([self Check:myKey.text] == YES){
        NSLog(@"OK");
        MainPageViewController *myLoginViewController = [[MainPageViewController alloc] initWithNibName:nil bundle:nil];
        [self presentModalViewController:myLoginViewController animated:NO];
    }else{
        NSLog(@"Problem!!");
    }
}

Comment: is you nib named MainPageViewController or why do you set the nib name to nil? Are you sure you want to have a MainPageViewController as your  modal view?

Comment: i have 2 viewController. First one is FirstViewController, and second one is MainPageViewController, which i want to reach on FirstViewController after the authentication. Authentication will be on FirstViewController. And i write that function on FirstViewController